# How to remove deleted entries from the main sphinx index?

Tags: sphinx

I have a site that utilizes the main/delta indexing scheme for sphinx. main gets rebuilt daily, delta is rebuilt every 5 minutes. This works well for indexing newly submitted items.

The problem is, items needed to be dropped from the index just as frequently as they are added, and typically the dropped items are older, so they already reside in the main index. So after item is deleted, they still appear in the search results for up to 24 hours (until 1am when main is rebuilt).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should probably remove the thinking-sphinx tag, as thinking-sphinx is a documentation system for Ruby.

Comment: If kill lists was a solution then you have to accept the answer about kill lists usage. Thanks.

Comment: @chris - Thinking Sphinx is a Ruby wrapper for Sphinx.

Answer (score 2):

See documentation for the sql_query_killlist http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-killlist

In nutshell  you need following in the delta index:

```
sql_query_killlist = select id from mytable where updated > @last_delta_update
```

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx recently introduced a realtime indexes feature, where you can add, update, and delete indexes on the fly.  However, it's only available in 1.10, and still seems pretty raw.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes

Alternatively, you could full re-index more often.  Every 24 hours seems kind of long, if you have a lot of deletions.  As a last-ditch effort, you could always check back in your application that the IDs being returned do indeed still exist, and then filter those out.

Comment: actually kill_list was the solution to the problem, without using 1.0

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define an attribute in the index, and then change the value of it to "ignore" certain documents.
For example, my indexes have a flag_ignore attribute. All searches are filtered so only those documents with flag_ignore=0 are matched.
When a document needs to disappear *right now* from the index, I call Sphinx->UpdateAttributes() and set the value to 1, which will make the document disappear from any following search.